# Convert multiple dta files to tab separated files in Stata

Tags: stata

Is there a way to convert a number of dta files to tab separated files at once, without loading each data set into Stata?

Something like :

```
x<- get *.dta filenames from directory
foreach file_with_filename in x
     convert to tab separated file
```

Apparently the *outsheet* function can be only used by referring to the dataset (or variable names) currently loaded in memory.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this. Here `fs` is a convenience command that you need to install, but only once.

```
clear 
ssc inst fs, replace
fs *.dta 

foreach f in `r(files)' {
    use "`f'" 
    local newname : subinstr local f ".dta" ".txt" 
    outsheet using `newname'
}
```

Note that `outsheet` is a command, not a function.

(edited to remove forcing of comma separation; question was about tab separation)